# How does HTML 5's input type email work and is it reliable?

Tags: html, validation, user-interface, input, user-experience

I'm making a form that takes e-mail addresses and am deciding whether to use `input type='email'` or `input type='text'` and do the validation using JavaScript. I know determining whether an e-mail addresses is of a valid format or not is a difficult task so does anyone know how good a job HTML 5's email attribute does of it?

Reasons to use email attribute

- Saves me from programing a complex regular expression
- Code readability
- Looks nice when given an invalid e-mail address

Reasons not to use email attribute

- Do not know how accurate it works
- For invalid input the looks is different than the rest of the input fields of the form

EDIT: Anyone know how `e-mail` attribute works in the sense what regular expression it uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facts about HTML5's `<input type="email">` :

1. Every browsers handle email validation differently. Opera accept `*@*` as a valid email address. In Safari, Chrome and Firefox you need to enter at least `*@*.*`
2. Not all browsers "support" type="email". You still could use type="email" but browser will threat it as type="text" if they don't recognize type="email"
3. On iPhone, when you arrive at input with type="email", iPhone will display "@" at keyboard's main screen, makes your application to be more user friendly
4. You can provide regular expression when using type="email"

My suggestions is you should start using this new HTML5 attribute along with your own validation to achieve point (3) above.

For more info :

1. http://davidwalsh.name/html5-email
2. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/#.UesKldKl5KU
3. http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

Hopefully this help.

Comment: I'd like to add that Android will display an @ too. I'd assume that by now all modern browsers perform this type of input validation. IE, Chrome and Firefox certainly do.

Answer (score 2):

I have used it and liked it.  However I had to override the validation error message. Here is how I did that.

```
//Listen for the 'input' event on the email field.  If HTML5 validation throws a typeMismatch, then
// override the default message with something more useful and/or sarcastic.
$('#email').bind('input', function () {
    //We need to reset it to blank or it will throw an invalid message.
    this.setCustomValidity('');
    if (!this.validity.valid) {
        this.setCustomValidity("Dude '" + this.value + "' is not a valid email. Try something like "+
            "jim@email.org. And no we are not checking if it actually works, we are just looking "+
            "for the @ sign. ");
    }
});
```

You can find this in a working example at [github](https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart/blob/master/kitchensink-backbone/src/main/webapp/index.html).